# Google analytic for google maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-analytics, analytics

I am creating a store locator application for desktop usage that contain 100+ stores.
I'm trying to create analytic for this app.

I know that I can create my own scripts and graphs and collect the user journey, clicks, search,... But i was wondering is it possible to link google analytic to google maps API in someway? or is there any other google platform that allows me to collect the user data and journey?

Thank

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/reports/maps-analytics

This is the link for Analytics for Google Maps. You can enable it and it will monitor without you having to add any additional code.